# A simple manner to get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{(nk)^2t^{1/(nk)^2}}=1/t$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, and $t>2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, special-functions, mobius-function

Introducing, by means of an artificial way, the [Riesz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_function) in the integrand of the [offset logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) one has for $X>2$ that 
$$\operatorname{Li}(X)=\int_2^X \frac{t}{\log ^2 t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Riesz}\left(\frac{\log t}{n^2}\right)dt=\int_2^X\frac{t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)t^{-1/(nk)^2}}{(nk)^2}}{\log t}dt.$$

Then as *corollary* one has that

**Fact.** Let a real number $t>2$, then the numerator of the integrand in second integral is $1.$

Now I don't know if my calculations to introduce the Riesz function in the integral of the logarithmic function aren't necessary to prove previous fact, and neither I know how think get with the tricks that I know about the theory of Möbius inversion. Can you prove it? That is can you answer this

> **Question.** Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, can you prove (directly, or using a statement that you do know: Möbius inversion or other) that for $t>2$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{(nk)^2t^{1/(nk)^2}}=\frac{1}{t}?$$
>   If it is well know, you can provide me the name of the theorem and hints to get it. **Many thanks.**

I believe that my calculations to get the first identity are rights, ask if you need it. Thus if you find a mistake, I am saying if the identity in Question is wrong, tell us.

Comment: If the way that I did is the only one, and the identity is obvious you can tell me in comments as advice, because I understand that my calculations were very  artificious. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that the $n$ is always grouped with the $k$ is suspicious, so let's reindex over $u=nk$ to get $$\sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k|u} \mu(k)}{u^2 t^{1/u^2}}$$
The numerator is the Dirichlet convolution of $\mu(n)$ with the constant $1(n)$ function, and it's a well known result that it's equal to 1, so we have $$\sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2 t^{1/u^2}}$$
I don't see a way to tackle that, though.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @CodeLabMaster . If the identity is true (I say in the case that we cann't find a counterexample, and some user can find a proof) then yours is a great simplification. If in next days you can find a countexexample tell me.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's clear that $\sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2t^{1/u^2}} \neq \frac{1}{t}$ since the LHS can be written as $\frac{1}{t} + \sum_{u=2}^\infty \frac{1}{u^2t^{1/u^2}}$ and the terms in the summation are positive for $t>2$.

Comment: Many thanks @CodeLabMaster , I have doubts about my identity, thus I was asking here if is right or wrong. My problems as I said is that was deduced by means of calculations that I believe artificious. On the other hand by means of examples for $t>2$ using Wolfam Alpha, I don't find now *counterexamples* (see the following good approaximation for $1/e$) for my identity:     sum mu(k)/(kn)^2 e^(-1/(kn)^2), from k=1 to k=100, from n=1 to n=100   Thus I accept your words and identity, but I don't understand now what's happens. Can you find a counterexample from my genuine identiy? Many thanks.

Comment: Now I understand where could be a mistake in your reasoning, your identity for $\sum_{k\mid n}\mu(k)$ isn't the contant function $1$, $\forall n\geq 1$. Many thanks @CodeLabMaster

Comment: Ah, that's actually the completed proof of your identity. $\sum_{d|u} \mu(k)$ is equal to 1 for $u=1$ and 0 for $u \neq 1$, thus proving what you were looking for. I'll leave my comments so that the conversation doesn't disappear, but I'll repost my corrected comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances of $n$ appear multiplied by $k$, which implies reindexing by $nk$ might lead us somewhere. Setting $u=nk$ gives us

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{(nk)^2 t^{1/(nk)^2}}  = \sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k|u} \mu(k)}{u^2 t^{1/u^2}} $$

The numerator is the Dirichlet convolution of $\mu(n)$ with the constant function $1(n)$ yielding the identity function of the convolution $\epsilon(n) = [n=1]$. Using that yields the conclusion

$$\sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k|u} \mu(k)}{u^2 t^{1/u^2}} = \sum_{u=1}^\infty \frac{[u=1]}{u^2 t^{1/u^2}} = \frac{1}{t} $$

Comment: you need to say it converges $\sum_n \sum_k \mu(k) (nk)^{-2}a(nk)$ converges absolutely whenever $a_n = \mathcal{O}(1)$ so that $\sum_n \sum_k \mu(k) (nk)^{-2}a(nk) = a(1)$

Comment: Sorry by my previous comment, now I understand your notation. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks also to you @user1952009